# Office web apps alternative for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, odf

Is there a asp.net component to allow in browser editing of doc, xls, ppt files alternative of Office web apps?

**Note for bounty**: as i wrote in a comment  i would like to write an app (not necessarily asp.net) in which the end user can edit MS Office (or Open Office) documents in browser. Is there  some solution for this? I guess a solution is also linking the app strongly to Google Drive or Office Web Apps but it is something I would like to avoid for now.
I leave "asp.net" in the title even if I could develop also on other platforms. I am in an R&D phase where technology is still a variable.

Comment: Try googling it https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+office+components

Comment: of course i tried to google before asking and if you try to read the search results you got lots of components to manipulate office documents (like modifying programmatically an xls file). What I would like to have is the possibility to add to a web application (not necessarly asp.net) an in browser editor, as done by google drive or office web apps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's *exactly* what you want, but there is a powerful library which is called [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/). It allows you to create Word/Excel/PowerPoint documents as well as documents of several other formats. There are versions for .NET and Java, and even cloud API.

I have some experience using this library in a different way, but I can say that it's very good in generating documents at back-end. And it's not connected to MS Office or Google Docs. I'm not sure about web components, but it seems that they have some: [e.g for excel](http://www.aspose.com/demos/.net-components/aspose.cells/csharp/grid/common/import-or-export-file.aspx)

Also, I should mention, that it's not free - don't know if it's a problem in your case.

Probably you should check it out, maybe it can fit your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Don't search for "Office", search for ["Open Document Format"](http://www.opendocumentformat.org/developers/) instead. You may want to try [WebODF](http://webodf.org/about/) JavaScript library which you can easily install on your existing web application.

Here is the [demonstation](http://webodf.org/demo/) and [gitgub](https://github.com/kogmbh/WebODF/) page.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from the file if its a doc and place them in rad control update what you want then save and the changes will be applied on file back.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the link below this should fit in your requirement.

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpreadWeb/

Online Demo: http://demo.componentone.com/spread7v2/controlexplorer/samples/Dashboard/Overview.aspx

Note: this is not available for free.